# Is there an error in this published R function for computing optimality prob. of Binomial Multi-Arm Bandits?

Tags: r

A researcher from Google, Steven Scott, published a paper called "[A Modern Bayesian Look at the Multi-Armed Bandit](http://www.economics.uci.edu/~ivan/asmb.874.pdf)" in **Applied Stochastic Models in Business and Industry**.

On page 649 in Figure 4 he gives a set of 3 R functions for computing optimality probability of a Binomial Multi-Arm Bandit by simulation:

```
sim.post <- function(y, n, ndraws){
  k   <- length(y)
  ans <- matrix(nrow=ndraws, ncol=k)
  no  <- n-y
  for(i in 1:k){
    ans[,i] <- rbeta(ndraws,y[i]+1,no[i]+1)
    return(ans)
  }
}

prob.winner <- function(post){
  k <- ncol(y)
  w <- table(factor(max.col(post), levels=1:k))
  return(w/sum(w))
}

compute.win.prob <- function(y, n, ndraws){
  return(prob.winner(sim.post(y,n,ndraws)))
}
```

Where

`y` = the number of successful trials

`n` = the number of trials

`ndraws` = the number of draws for the simulation

Yet every time I try to use these functions I get an error relating to the fact that `y` doesn't have columns. This is not a problem in the function he gives on page 648 Figure 3 for calculation by integration.

```
y      <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
n      <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10)
ndraws <- 50

compute.win.prob(y = y, n = n, ndraws = ndraws)
```

> Error in 1:k : argument of length 0 Called from: factor(max.col(post),
>   levels = 1:k)

Is there a typo in this formula and if so, what's the fix for it?

Comment: There surely is an error because `prob.winner` uses the variable `y` that is not defined in the function. Perhaps that `y` should be `post`. it would be better to contact the author directly about something so specific to his code.

Comment: @MrFlick I reached out to him but didn't hear back. I tried plugging in `post` but the results don't make sense with that substitution.

Comment: The `return()` from `sim.post()` inside the `for` loop looks wrong - if you move this after the loop, and change `ncol(y)` to `length(y)` in `prob.winner()` it runs, but I've no idea if it runs *correctly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if this code makes sense or not, but I fixed two fairly obvious errors and get this. I marked the changes inline using comments.

```
sim.post <- function(y, n, ndraws){
  k   <- length(y)
  ans <- matrix(nrow=ndraws, ncol=k)
  no  <- n-y
  for(i in 1:k){
    ans[,i] <- rbeta(ndraws,y[i]+1,no[i]+1)
  #  return(ans)  # Obviously wrong - move outside the loop
  }
  return(ans)
}

prob.winner <- function(post){
  k <- ncol(post) # change y to post
  w <- table(factor(max.col(post), levels=1:k))
  return(w/sum(w))
}

compute.win.prob <- function(y, n, ndraws){
  return(prob.winner(sim.post(y,n,ndraws)))
}

y      <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
n      <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10)
ndraws <- 50

compute.win.prob(y = y, n = n, ndraws = ndraws)
```

Result:

```
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.02 0.00 0.10 0.16 0.72
```

Comment: Note that `return(ans)` error is a transcription error of the OP. In the paper there are no braces for the `for` expression. The paper also correctly indents the return statement to show it is not in the scope of `for`.

Comment: @A.Webb Thanks for restoring my confidence in my fellow authors!